# Does Customs still check anyone?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I have done plenty of international travel in my lifetime. In the last 12 months alone, I have flown over 75,000 miles, all international, at least 10 countries (I've lost count). I've crossed countless borders, passports control, all of that. And an observation hit me recently: I haven't had my bag checked or seen anyone else's bag checked at customs in all of those miles!

Does customs check anyone's bags any more?

You would think that in all of that travel, it would have happened to me at least once. Or have seen other people that have been stopped. But every customs in every airport I've been in has been empty or lightly staffed or simply not used. I just walk right by and no one says anything.

My gut tells me that bag checks & x-rays that they do behind the scenes (and maybe even some of the passenger tracking) has become very sophisticated and those "public" checks are no longer needed. I mean, surely they have to be doing *some* sort of checks, right? So, what's going on here?

Comment: It really depends A LOT on the country. In Indonesia you need to fill out an online form, get a QR code, run your stuff through an X-ray and then line up  for an interview with customs officer for an interviews. In Germany, you'll have a hard time hunting down an officer if you have something to declare. There is also A LOT of visual profiling happening, some more obvious than others.

Comment: @Hilmar: And then you have Mexico, where they make you press a button, and it randomly lights up green or red (to determine whether you get screened or not).

Comment: It's fascinating to see how customs processes differ throughout the world. Mexico's random button system sounds like a unique approach, while Indonesia and Germany have their distinctive methods. Each country adds its flavor to the customs experience

Comment: In my scruffily-dressed, mildly-long-haired youth, I got my bags X-rayed a fair few times. Now I look like a boring middle-aged businessperson and customs officials don't even make *eye contact* with me.

Comment: In Australia and New Zealand you *will* be scanned for biosecurity. I'm not sure if it's technically the same department as customs.

Comment: [This covers EU, UK, far east & USA] Anecdotally, back in the 80s I was in a rock band. We were checked at **every** customs, **every** time, presumably based on 'rock band == drugs'. There was never anything to find. In the 90s working for a multinational instrument/electronics manufacturer, we'd be stopped to show them the electronics we were carrying, usually so they could ooh & aahh at them. Since then, no-one has ever paid me any heed. I haven't seen staff in a customs hall in 20 years - so much so that on tourist holidays I just use it as an excuse to fill a suitcase with fags & booze ;)

Comment: At FDH airport (tiny local airport in Germany), you will typically see customs staff waiting in their room next to the exit for anyone who wants to declare goods, but only once have I seen them actively asking passengers into their room for screening. Not sure if this was due to the time of day - that last flight arrived around 10am, while the others arrived around 9pm, with closing time drawing near - or because they knew there would be a much larger number of passengers coming in from outside the EU on the morning flight.

Comment: In the US, you generally have to line up for immigration, and I think people may not always realize that the immigration officer is also charged with performing customs functions at their discretion. They can definitely send you to secondary. Beyond that, I once had a customs officer stop me in the open baggage reclaim area and question me, based (as far as I can tell) on the fact that I smiled at him as I walked by. Big mistake.

Comment: How long ago counts as "still"?  I was checked by US customs about 20 years ago when I was living in Amsterdam and traveling between there and New York frequently.  I suppose that a single man with that fact pattern might be as likely to have his bags searched today as I was then, but since I no longer meet the fact pattern I wouldn't know.  I was also stopped maybe 10 years ago for a supposedly random secondary inspection at Alexandria Bay ("supposedly" because everyone there seemed to be at risk for profiling for one reason or another).

Comment: @Tetsujin that reminds me of my first trip on the train from Amsterdam to Berlin, which was in late 1999.  I was in a compartment with a 20-something Polish woman with blond dreadlocks, liberally pierced and tattooed.  A German officer went through her bag, which was packed full in a somewhat disorganized manner, and he left about half of its contents on the seat beside her.  Finally, he asked, in English, "is there drugs in here?"  She smiled and laughed a bit as she said "no," as if you say "I wouldn't be so stupid."  He then left, having barely looked at me.

Comment: @phoog They still do bag searches in the US, it is not something from the history. I was sent there quite recently, but then they let me go after another interview. But I saw many other people had their bags opened there.

Comment: Once, when i was flying from Montreal to Dallas (the US CPB does pre-clearance in Montreal) with a Nexus card (a US-Canada trusted traveller program), the officer I talked to pulled up an XRay of my bag and asked what something that showed up in the image was. I've been US-Canada traveling _a lot_ over the past 30+ years. They know much more than they look like they do.

Comment: Where do you think all these customs finds documentation/reality shows have their footage from ;)

Answer (score 13):

It happens in some places, like China, Malaysia, Indonesia, etc, where all arriving passengers are asked to put their luggage through x-ray machines right before exiting. In other places seemingly random passengers are asked to do so.

In Japan it's one-on-one interviews with a Customs officer, who may decide to go through manually through your stuff, or not, and even pat you down.

In some countries like South Korea, Indonesia again, and I suppose plenty more, luggage is x-rayed right off the plane, and suspicious luggage tagged for secondary inspection. Happened to me in both places.

Comment: If you *want* to get pulled out of line, bring bags of metal-twined pipe cleaners in your luggage. I'm pretty sure they CT scan everything at all the major ports.

Comment: some places??? i see it regularly... like everywhere. lately i traveled around europe and turkey.

Answer (score 11):

I have seen inspections happen in the Netherlands, (the airport I used most,) but not often.

It was almost always people with carts overflowing with suitcases, often also from non-European ethnicity.

I myself have had luggage checked in the USA and Australia, both cases after I had indicated that I was carrying something they might be blocking out of the country and after inspecting, and allowing, said item there was a bored and not too detailed check of the whole luggage.

Comment: +1, my carry-on bags were checked by Customs in Schiphol/Amsterdam this month flying out of the Netherlands to England… they didn’t care about my dozens of [kroketten](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=febo+kroketten) (food) but they thought my apple tart might have drugs in it  One swab of the appeltaart on the drug machine and a quick conversation about Dutch delicacies and I was on my way  (I had no suitcase, easyJet charge more for a bag than a flight)

Comment: I had to go hunt down a customs inspector when leaving schipol, to declare the cat I was bringing in to the country from the UK - it was kind of amusing, having to duck through the restricted bit to knock on the little cabin he was in to get some help - I guess they're deployed for higher risk flights?  Was a great customs officer, though - super friendly, big hit with our normally demonic cat.

Answer (score 7):

Secondary inspection has never happened out where you can see it. That one person who is standing around near where you just swan on by can and does tell some people "right this way, please."

I got sent to secondary twice entering the US and once entering Australia. It is quite likely the people around me didn't even notice. I just went through a different door or over to a different line up. I understand that sometimes people are invited back to secondary before they even line up for primary -- eg from the baggage belt or even the jetway -- thanks to tech like facial recognition, xraying bags, and so on, as well as the usual "looking nervous" heuristic.

As an experienced traveller who isn't carrying a lot of stuff, you and I are among the least likely to get secondaried. But I'm quite sure it's still happening.

Comment: But that's what I'm saying, there isn't even a line-up! There's no secondary search because I've never even seen a primary search. All I see is bunch of empty tables and maybe 1 or 2 guards standing around talking with each other. But I just don't see anyone stopped any more or any lines for either primary or secondary.

Comment: At DFW they have remodeled the international arrivals to eliminate the customs lines that were there ~5 years ago that everyone had to go through. I wasn’t paying close attention, but walked right over to the Global Entry portion of immigration without seeing anyone being diverted, or even a place to divert them to. All quite welcome but it felt really weird.

Comment: there are still doors, and arches and such. They get you from the public area to the private area very quickly and discreetly. Those guards will flip from casually talking to each other to "come with me please" in a heartbeat. And you are being assessed, it's just not obvious while you stand at a table with papers out.

Comment: Agreed, but nobody was asking ‘do you have anything to declare’ at all in the first place. Just grab bags off the carousel and go through immigration. Done…

Comment: @JonCuster, by grabbing your luggage and leaving the area you indicate you have nothing to declare. If you have something to declare you go to an officer and declare.

Comment: @Willeke, you're absolutely right. The process has become more streamlined, with technology playing a significant role in pre-screening. It's efficient but might feel unusual for seasoned travelers.

Comment: "Secondary inspection has never happened out where you can see it." Never say never. It happens regularly in some of the countries I travel to frequently.

Comment: @Willeke that feels like it's trying to trip you up. In some airports you have to go through a door that says "nothing to declare" and there are posters saying what you have to declare.

Comment: @user253751, I assume there are 'declare here' signs on the wall, which those in a hurry will ignore.

Comment: "has never happened out where you can see it": at JFK they have tables for conducting searches that are just to the side of the checkpoint that travelers have to walk through to leave the baggage hall.  At least they used to; they've reconfigured things there and I've only been there once since, so I don't remember the details of the changes.

Comment: @JonCuster at every US airport I've entered, it's immigration first, then get your bags, then walk with your bags past the customs checkpoint. The opportunity to declare is, however, at the immigration checkpoint, where you formerly had to give the immigration officer an actual declaration form. I've never used a US kiosk but I believe they similarly ask whether you have anything to declare. That's at least what you can read at https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/know-before-you-go/what-expect-when-you-return, but since it doesn't agree with my experience I take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 5):

I have been stopped in:

- USA (Boston)
- UAE (Dubai); there were five officers that came over and actually split open my wallet looking for weed... but never checked my pockets
- UK (Manchester) my local airport and Heathrow almost every single time I return, including with sniffer dogs
- Australia (Melbourne)
- Turkey (Antalya)
- Japan (Tokyo)

Probably others that I can't now recall. Twice this year alone.

Yes. Trust me, you can still be pulled in Customs; you can imagine I also have the same "fun" while trying to board the plane through Security, too. I have an unfortunate combination of:

- I'm very underweight because of digestive issues
- I have blotchy skin on my face, probably due to the former
- I used to keep my contact lenses in on the plane, which could make my eyes bloodshot with the dry air. I've since taken them out and put them back in on landing... that approach hasn't worked at all, so that theory is out.

I guess I just look like a quintessential drug smuggler :/

Comment: The “never checked my pockets” is real. Once coming into Liverpool my friend and I were searched, made to take off our coats, emptied our bags, but didn’t check our pockets. I asked why, and I will never forget her response: “If it’s that small we’re not interested”.

Comment: @DannyBeckett I was mega stressed having 5 guys from security come up to me and I was travelling alone for work. It doesn't matter if you're innocent, the pressure is high. It was only afterwards that I was really bemused about how stupid the whole search was when they split all the lining of my wallet but never asked about my pockets

Answer (score 4):

In Frankfurt, there are two big doors leading out of the baggage collection area, one marked bright red with a large sign reading "Goods to declare", the other marked bright green "Nothing to declare".

I have seen multiple times people getting stopped and questioned, pulled aside into a side room, or both, when going through the green door.

I would assume the frequency and thoroughness of those spot checks depends on what flights recently landed. For example, coming back from Australia via Hong Kong, I saw a lot more customs officers than coming back from Dresden.

Comment: A flight from Dresden wouldn't have any need for customs because it's domestic... which is why they apparently don't bother to staff the customs checkpoint at that time.

Comment: @user253751 couldn't you have an international flight to say frankfurt or munich and a connecting flight to dresden?

Comment: @infinitezero you could, but then you would have to declare your goods at the first entry point in the EU (Frankfurt or Munich).

Comment: @matteroffact I was under the impression that your luggage gets automatically transferred. How would you declare it?

Comment: @matteroffact customs formalities for checked baggage in the EU are typically handled at the final destination, where the passenger retrieves those bags.  The answer concerns flights from Dresden to Frankfurt, and there probably is no airline that will sell you a ticket from a non-EU airport to Frankfurt via Dresden nor check your luggage through on such an itinerary.  Therefore, no luggage on the plane would be subject to customs inspection. Even if such a flight is somehow possible, it will be very unlikely as there is far more capacity to Frankfurt and Munich.

Comment: @matteroffact It is in the final destination, not in the first entry point. The customs staff look for people with bag tags from outside of EU when flights from well-known international hubs based in EU arrive. And people without any tag are the most suspicious because they might have thrown it away to avoid the check. Often, the check is only an interview, it depends how the customs got satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

I had a custom officer talk to me at Osaka/Kansai and ask me to open my luggage. Another time was in Singapore when everyone put their bags in X-ray machine for inspection. So conclusion is sometimes custom officers check passengers bags.

Answer (score 2):

Coming from China to the US we have gotten plenty of agricultural inspections.  Admittedly, we haven't gone since the great yuck.

(Hey, guys, I was referring to Covid, not the previous occupant of the Oval Office!)

Comment: First time I've seen Trump described that way.

Comment: If "the great yuck" is Trump, why not say Trump? Without the aboves comment I've never understood what that might be.

Comment: I read it as Covid.

Comment: @Max It’s a joke, possibly in reference to Trump calling Covid “kung-flu”